# Why does "append('w')" return None?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
def list_test(foo):
    bar = foo.append('w')
    return bar

my_input = [7,8,9]
```

When i run it:

```
>>>print list_test(my_input)
None
```

It's printout `None`. Why? How can I fix that?

**Note:** Output i need is: `7,8,9,'w'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`list.append()` returns None to underscore the fact that it is a mutating call. Such calls, that modify their argument, generally return None. Calls that create  a *new* list return it.

If it is important that `list_test` return the modified list, then your code might be better like this:

```
def list_test(foo):
    foo.append('w')
    return foo

my_input = [7,8,9]

>>> print list_test(my_input)
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
>>> print my_input
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
```

But, if I were writing this, I would follow the convention that mutating calls return None, and write it this way:

```
def list_test(foo):
    foo.append('w')

my_input = [7,8,9]

>>> print list_test(my_input)
None
>>> print my_input
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
```

Finally, if you want list_test to be non-mutating, that is it should return a new list and not modify its input, one of these might work for you:

```
def list_test(foo):
    new_foo = list(foo)
    new_foo.append('w')
    return new_foo

def list_test(foo):
    return foo + ['w']

my_input = [7,8,9]

>>> print list_test(my_input)
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
>>> print my_input
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: so, how can i fix this?

Comment: but what should i write in my function, so when i run it, it's printout [7, 8, 9, 'w'] but when i run "my_input" it's return [7, 8, 9]?

Answer (score 3):

[`append`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) will not return the list but mutate the original list. So after calling `foo.append()`, foo’s content changed. As such `foo` itself is the “new” (and old) list with the new element. So you could just write your function like this:

```
def list_test(foo):
    foo.append('w')
    return foo
```

Note that this also means that the original list you passed to the function changed as well:

```
>>> my_input = [7,8,9]
>>> list_test(my_input)
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
>>> my_input
[7, 8, 9, 'w']
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `append()` works in-place, i.e. modifies `foo` directly instead of creating a new list.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` doen't return anything useful because it only modifies its argument (list). You probably want to return `foo` instead